# Scrolling to show and display elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, ecmascript-6

i am trying to get to show/display elements when i scroll. So far i'm unsuccessful, but i hope you can help me.

I am using jQuery at the moment because of the .heigh() and .scrollTop() methods, but i would rather use plain JS.

my code so far

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
<div class="toShow"></div>
```

Sass

```
.container
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  overflow: auto
  border: 3px solid crimson
  box-sizing: border-box

.filler
  width: 100%
  height: 200px
  border: 2px solid green

.toShow
  width: 50%
  height: 100px
  background-color: navy
  display: none
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  left: 0
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var H = $(".container").scrollTop() / 2
      var contH = $(".container").height()
      if(H > contH ){
            $(".toShow").fadeIn()
            console.log("yes")
      }else{
            $(".toShow").fadeOut()
      }
  })
}.call(this))
```

and the [PEN](https://codepen.io/angus/pen/rmLXEK) here

Comment: Check this awesome plugin: https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/ or https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Comment: can't get neither to work…